# Android multiple listviews with checkbox

Tags: android

I'm new to Android programing. I need to create a list of 1000 goods for users to click and check or the one they want to buy.  I've created the array list and added it to my custom adapter and I have also added it to my list view. my problem is how to get the position for each item selected and I need clarification on the getView and the ViewHolder. I'm not working with toast

Answer (score 0):

See the below tutorials,

http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/04/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

http://developerandro.blogspot.in/2013/09/listview-with-checkbox-android-example.html

http://aboutyusata.blogspot.in/2013/11/how-to-make-listview-with-checkbox-in.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ListView getCheckedItemPositions()

```
 /**
 * Returns the set of checked items in the list. The result is only valid if
 * the choice mode has not been set to {@link #CHOICE_MODE_NONE}.
 *
 * @return  A SparseBooleanArray which will return true for each call to
 *          get(int position) where position is a checked position in the
 *          list and false otherwise, or <code>null</code> if the choice
 *          mode is set to {@link #CHOICE_MODE_NONE}.
 */
public SparseBooleanArray getCheckedItemPositions() {
    if (mChoiceMode != CHOICE_MODE_NONE) {
        return mCheckStates;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getView()` method is called when new list item that is adapted is being shown on your screen. That is why you need to take good care of the memory and `setTag()` for every item you inflate. Then when old item is viewed again you will not render it like a new one but get it by the tag you submitted for that item.

Example: If you have 1000 items only couple of those will be shown on the screen and your program will call `getView()` for those items that are visible plus for couple of items bellow those that are visible so you don't see the lag in inflation while scrolling.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if(view==null)
       {
         LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
         view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
         TextView textView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_hint);
         ImageView imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img);
         // here we will setTag() our view later
       }
    //... (here we will manage the views and set some click listeners)
```

Now, what is a **viewHolder**?

The **ViewHolder** basically is the private class inside your *adapter* that is used to keep you inflated layout elements together and to let you manipulate those view after you got the using **findViewById(int resId)**.

Some code:

```
private class ViewHolder{
     public ImageView imageView;
     public TextView textView;

     public ViewHolder(ImageView imageView,TextView textView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
        this.textView = textView;
     }
}
```

Now to setTag() as promised.

```
view.setTag(new Holder(imageView,textView));
```

Now with this in mind you can get your ViewHolder using the code above and views that you got in the first part of my code. (this is what we will write instead of 3 dots)

```
    ViewHolder h = (Holder) view.getTag();
    h.textView.setText(ar[position]);
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(pic[position], "drawable", getPackageName());
    h.imageView.setImageResource(resID);
    // here I did set some source to my imageView that is in my layout, but 
    // you can do whatever you want with these views. And that is what I'm 
    // going to explain later in this text.
    return view;
}
```

Okay, what next?

After getting the ViewHolder from tag you have your entire layout as a View that can get his `OnClickListener` easily. Or just a checkBox can get `OnCheckedChangeListener`.

Inside methods for this listeners you can send the data to you controller (in case you are using MVC model) or to your activity that hosts this View, where you can save the state of the checkbox and title of the item that has been clicked.

For example you can do something like this on your corresponding listener method:

```
(MainActivity)context.markAsChecked(String title);
```

But in this case you will also need to have the opposite method for unchecking

```
(MainActivity)context.markAsUnchecked(String title);
```

and you will have to handle this in your MainActivity properly by browsing through the array of data that has been selected.

The second solution is to have :

```
(MainActivity)context.toggleState(String title);
```

And to handle both events checked and unchecked.

Your method  in your Activity would need to do something similar to this:

```
public void toggleState(String title){
      if (data.contains(title))
          data.remove(title);
      else data.add(title);
}
```

Then after your user checks what he wants you will have all the checked elements in your data array that in this case is **ArrayList**. You can also you HashMap for this if you like or something else too.

Hope this helps.
I will be more than happy to answer all of your questions if have some more.

Maybe controller implementation is something that you would like to consider in this case. That would mean that you would be using MVC model for better control of your app and data, and to delegate the tasks to responsible classes and methods. Not to put everything in one Activity :)

Bye